# Inserting/Updating Rows to DB table where Rows result from VO [Backed by EO] based on Union Query

Tags: oracle-adf, bc4j

Jdev Version : 11.1.1.7

I have created a Department VO based Department EO with the following query :

```
SELECT DeptEO.DEPARTMENT_ID,
   DeptEO.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
   DeptEO.MANAGER_ID,
   DeptEO.LOCATION_ID,
   DeptEO.ACTIVE
FROM DEPARTMENTS DeptEO where DeptEO.DEPARTMENT_ID > 250
UNION
SELECT 280 , 'Advertising',200,1700,'Y' from Dual
```

For the simplicity , I have used a sample statement from dual table , in real scenario , the query after UNION clause will populate from a table.
After running the query ,I get the result that is desired on the UI .

Now my requirement is to insert this newly created  row with DEPARTMENT_ID as 280 , into DB table DEPARTMENTS.
While committing , ADF throws error as " oracle.jbo.RowAlreadyDeletedException: JBO-29114 " which is correct as the this row is missing from DB table , so when it goes for taking a lock on the row for update , it doesn't find anything .

Is there any way that i can instruct ADF to consider this row for Insert rather than update .
We also tried to populate the data of this row into a new row instance created from RowSetIterator , and afterwards remove the culprit row by calling removeFromCollection() and then inserting the duplicated row , but still no luck .

Other approaches that we are thinking of are :

1- Create another VO/EO and insert values in table through them .
2- Create a DB View for this query and trigger on this view , so when ever an update operation comes , we do our logic in trigger i.e. decide whether to update or insert the data.

Can you please guide what should be done in such scenario .

Regards,

Siddharth

Edit : Code for Inserting Row (What I was trying but it's not working)

```
    RowSetIterator rsi=iterator.getRowSetIterator();
   Row editableRow= rsi.createRow();

    while(rsi.hasNext()){
        Row r =rsi.next();

        if((""+r.getAttribute("DepartmentId")).toString().equals("280") ){
            System.err.println("? Equality row found!!!");
            editableRow.setAttribute("DepartmentId", r.getAttribute("DepartmentId"));
            editableRow.setAttribute("DepartmentName", r.getAttribute("DepartmentName"));
            editableRow.setAttribute("ManagerId", r.getAttribute("ManagerId"));
            editableRow.setAttribute("LocationId", r.getAttribute("LocationId"));
            editableRow.setAttribute("Active", r.getAttribute("Active"));

            rsi.removeCurrentRowFromCollection();
        }
    }

    if(editableRow !=null){
        System.err.println("? Row value after removal : "+editableRow.getAttribute("DepartmentName"));

        rsi.insertRow(editableRow);
        operBindingCommit.execute();
    }
```

Comment: please post how you are trying to insert the newly created row

Comment: To better understand your requirement, you want to add a department with id 280 if it does not exist in database otherwise update the existing?

Comment: @amishra Hi , yes you are right . This is the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case can be implemented in a couple of ways. First way is to iterate over row set in managed bean and check if department with id 280 exists, if yes then update the row otherwise invoke Create with parameters for department VO. The second way, and would say the better way, is to create a method for update/insert at business component level, either in ViewObjectImpl or in ApplicationModuleImpl and then invoke it from managed bean.

Here is the sample code for insert/update method written in VOImpl

```
public void updateInsertJobs(String jobId, String jobTitle,
                           String minSalary, String maxSalary)
    {
    RowSetIterator rSet = this.createRowSetIterator(null);
    JobsViewRowImpl row = new JobsViewRowImpl();
    Boolean jobExist = false;
    if (null != jobId)
    {
      try
      {
        while (rSet.hasNext())
        {
          row = (JobsViewRowImpl) rSet.next();
          if (row.getJobId().equals(jobId))
          {
            row.setJobTitle(jobTitle);
            row.setMinSalary(new Number(minSalary));
            row.setMaxSalary(new Number(maxSalary));
            jobExist = true;
          }
        }
        if (!jobExist)
        {
          JobsViewRowImpl r = (JobsViewRowImpl) this.createRow();
          r.setJobId(jobId);
          r.setJobTitle(jobTitle);
          r.setMinSalary(new Number(minSalary));
          r.setMaxSalary(new Number(maxSalary));
          this.insertRow(r);
        }
        this.getDBTransaction().commit();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

Make sure to expose the method in Client Interface in order to be able to access it from data control.

Here is how to invoke the method from managed bean:

```
public void insertUpdateData(ActionEvent actionEvent)
{
    BindingContainer bc =
       BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
     OperationBinding oB = bc.getOperationBinding("updateInsertJobs");
    oB.getParamsMap().put("jobId", "TI_STF");
    oB.getParamsMap().put("jobTitle", "Technical Staff");
    oB.getParamsMap().put("minSalary", "5000");
    oB.getParamsMap().put("maxSalary", "18000");
    oB.execute();
}
```

Some references which could be helpful:

- http://mahmoudoracle.blogspot.com/2012/07/adf-call-method-from-pagedefinition.html#.VMLYaf54q-0
- http://adftidbits.blogspot.com//2014/11/update-vo-data-programatically-adf.html
- http://www.awasthiashish.com/2012/12/insert-new-row-in-adf-viewobject.html

Answer (score 0):

Your view object become readonly due to custom sql query.
However you still can create row in dept table using entity.

Create java implemetation including accessors for `DeptEO`.
Create custom method in view object and create new entity or update existing using entity definition there. To find that required row exist, you can check that entity with this key is already exists. Something like this (assuming deptId is your primary key):

```
  public void createOrUpdateDept(BigInteger deptId){
    DeptEOImpl dept;
    EntityDefImpl deptDef = DeptEOImpl.getDefinitionObject();

    Key key = new Key(new Object[]{deptId});
    dept = deptDef.findByPrimaryKey(getDBTransaction(), key);
    if (dept == null){
      // Creating new entity if it doesn't exist
      dept = deptDef.createInstance2(getDBTransaction(), null);
      dept.setDepartmentId(deptId);
    }

    // Changing other attributes
    dept.setDepartmentName("New name");

    // Commiting changes and refreshing ViewObject if required
    getDBTransaction().commit();
    executeQuery();
  }
```

*This code is just a sample, use it as reference/idea, don't blindly copy/paste.*